# SmtpFailedRecipientException

Tags: web-services

I already deployed it on server. But I've noticed that it still searching the path on my local.. Anyone know this issue?

here the error on server:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for margarrete@yahoo.com
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at EmailWebservices.EmailAcess.Send() in C:\Users\Desktop\proj\Mail\Mail\EmailAcess.cs:line 52 //path on my local is this a error?
   at EmailWebservices.Service1.SendMessage(String Mail, String AuthSTR) in C:\Users\Desktop\proj\Mail\Mail\Service1.asmx.cs:line 36 //path on my local is this a error?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your title and tags to be relevant.  "problem on server" is not a descriptive title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the error.
The filename in the stacktrace is the path to the *original* source file, coming from the PDB file.
It has nothing to do with the compiled DLL on the server.

The actual problem is that you didn't provide a login for your SMTP server (`SmtpClient.Credential = new NetworkCredential(...)`, so it's refusing to send external messages.

Comment: I'm confused. What should i do?

Comment: You should set `SmtpClient.Credential`